# RadioButton is checked, it's Checked event is call when run the app, and report exception

Tags: wpf, events, radio-button, initialization

There are two `RadioButton`s and two `Label`s in `.xaml`, and check one `RadioButton` make the corresponding `Label` Enable. `RadioButton1` is checked . Run the app, and the `Checked Event` is called automatically, but Label is null, so the app report exception.

I just use a variable to mark whether the window is first created. Whether there are other methods? I don't know why the app run the events after initialize all components, who can tell me?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton
            GroupName="Group"
            IsChecked="True"
            Content="RadioButton1"
            x:Name="RadioButton1"
            Checked="RadioButton1_Checked"
            Unchecked="RadioButton1_Unchecked"/>
        <RadioButton
            GroupName="Group"
            Content="RadioButton2"
            x:Name="RadioButton2"
            Checked="RadioButton2_Checked"
            Unchecked="RadioButton2_Unchecked"/>
        <Label
            x:Name="Label1"
            Content="Label1"/>
        <Label
            IsEnabled="False"
            x:Name="Label2"
            Content="Label2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool isFirstRun;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            isFirstRun = true;

            InitializeComponent();

            isFirstRun = false;
        }

        private void RadioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isFirstRun)
                return;
            Label1.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void RadioButton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void RadioButton1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void RadioButton2_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a specific reason for the `EventHandlers`, but if not you can do this logic directly in the `Xaml` using `ElementName` binding

Example:

```
 <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1"
                     GroupName="Group"
                     IsChecked="True"
                     Content="RadioButton1" />

        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2"
                     GroupName="Group"
                     Content="RadioButton2" />

        <Label x:Name="Label1"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton1}"
               Content="Label1"/>

        <Label x:Name="Label2"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton2}"
               Content="Label2"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply remove the `Ischecked="True"` from the XAML and replace the `isFirstRun = false` variable being set after `InitializeComponent();` with `RadioButton1.IsChecked = true`

this way you save having to define the `isFirstRun` variable.